# Cannot parse time string to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to convert this string `01:43:56` to a `LocalDateTime` but keep getting this error thrown:

> Text '01:43:56' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime
> from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 01:43:56 of type
> java.time.format.Parsed

I've tried every variation of the time format I can think of:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("01:43:56", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss"))
LocalDateTime.parse("01:43:56", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))
LocalDateTime.parse("01:43:56", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"))
LocalDateTime.parse("01:43:56", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:m:s"))
LocalDateTime.parse("01:43:56", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
```

Comment: LocalTime vs LocalDateTime may be Kris ?

 LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse("10:15:45");

Comment: I just learned there is a `LocalTime` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string "01:43:56" only contains time information without any date information, which is why you are getting an error when trying to parse it as a **LocalDateTime**.

You should use **LocalTime.parse()** instead of **LocalDateTime.parse()**:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String timeString = "01:43:56";

        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
        System.out.println(localTime); // Output: 01:43:56
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to specify a formatting pattern here. `LocalTime.parse( "01:43:56" )` will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

There is no date part in your input. Try with LocalTime instead.

Answer (score 2):

As others have already indicated, the problem is that a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) requires both a date and a time, and your format only has a time. As the other answers show, the general solution is to use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

However, if you really do need a `LocalDateTime`, you can also configure the formatter to apply a default value if none is available in the format:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.EPOCH_DAY, LocalDate.now().toEpochDay())
        .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
        .toFormatter();
```

This formatter configures a default value for the `EPOCH_DAY` field equal to the current date. This means that when the parsed value doesn't provide date information, it is taken from `EPOCH_DAY`.

That said, although this is an option, usually obtaining a `LocalDateTime` is easier done by using `LocalTime.parse("01:43:56").atDate(LocalDate.now())` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have only time in the string. You can parse it to `LocalTime`; or `LocalTimeDate` but additionally you have to set a required day, e.g. today.

```java
public static LocalDateTime convert(String str) {
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME);
    return localTime.atDate(LocalDate.now());
}
```